# C - bitwise compression and decompression

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift, compression

I'm wondering about something. I have a couple of *.txt-files containing four characters (multiple of each). The characters in the files are: ' ', ':'. '@' and '\n'.

What i want to do is to swap those standard ASCII-characters with something that uses less bits. ' ' should be swapped with 00, ':' should be swapped with 01, '@' should be swapped with 01 and '\n' should be swapped with 02.

The idea is to compress and later have the possibility to decompress the files again.

The thing is, my code doesn't work - and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your environment? How could you define and compile a function named `read`?

Comment: @LPs, it can be compiled because `unistd.h` is not included, anyway, you sould avoid these function names.

Comment: There is a big memory leak at `container = malloc(64000); ... container = malloc(size);` and your code doesn't seems portable due to endianness.

Comment: You need to `putc(swapped, fp);` only on every fourth character. There's a similar problem but in reverse in the decompression loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `compress` function try to open file to write with `rb+`. It
   triggers segmentation fault if file does not exists. BTW you must
   use `wb+` to write it.

   fp = fopen(file, "wb+");

   Always check the return of fopen to avoid to access a `null` file descriptor.
2. When you read the file from a compressed file into `container` you cannot then evaluate the length with `strlen`, because of it stops at the first '\0' char (0x00). E.g. Your compression change `' '` (space or 0x20) to 0x00. This means that strlen gives you the length until that char.
3. Variable `newCounter`, for the first time in for loop is `0`, the is not managed by your if-elseif. Your code should be:

---

```
   if(newCounter == 0)      swapped |= counter << 6;
   else if(newCounter == 1) swapped |= counter << 4;
   else if(newCounter == 2) swapped |= counter << 2;
   else                     swapped |= counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the `read` and `write` functions from the POSIX library.  Use a different name or make these `static`.

It is actually recommended to make all local functions in your program `static`.  This minimizes the risk of collision and allows the compiler to perform better optimizations.

You have other issues in your code, but this one is blocking all attempts at debugging.